# How to sum field values in collections in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  }
  likes: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  }, ],
  likeLength: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
});


let totalLikes = Post.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      postedBy: req.profile._id,
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$postedBy",
      total_count: {
        $sum: "$likeLength"
      }
    }
  },
])
```

I wanted to sum likeLength values in all Post collections filtered by postedBy field and get the summed result which type of integer. I tried totalLikes function above but could not make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for that is the following. With result[0] the result will be an object with sumLikes property.

```js
aggregate([
      {
        $match: {postedBy: req.profile._id}
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          sumLikes: {
            $sum: "$likeLength",
          },
        },
      },
      { $unset: ["_id"] },
    ], function(err, result) {
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
      }else{
        res.json(result[0])
      }})
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

- make the string `req.profile._id` to ObjectId
- group by `null` all are from the same `postedBy` so all document that passed are in group. (group by null means all collection 1 group) (your group was ok also but this is simpler)
- unset the `_id` to get as result  `[{"total_count" : 20}]` for example

*before testing the group test if `$match` works and documents are found.

```js
let totalLikes = Post.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      postedBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.profile._id),
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total_count: {
        $sum: "$likeLength"
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unset": ["_id"]}
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much . I also made it with this function $group: { _id: "$postedBy",sumLikes: {$sum: {$size: "$likes" }}}   But how to get this data , i mean integer , and send that number to client?

Comment: queries always returns arrays of documents (or empty array if nothing is found). The closer you can get is this  `[{total_count : 20 }]` if you want this you can remove the `_id` with `project` or `unset`

Comment: Thank you so much and i am really sorry for wasting your time but I think that is not my problem. I use react on the client and when I get this data from the server I encounter with this {_pipeline: Array(3), options: {…}} so how can i reach my number :). However I probably have to ask a new question for that because of the website's format.

Comment: aggregations return cursors, and they have many methods, one simple one is `toArray()`
and from there you get them with js after. see the mongoose documentation

Comment: actually i use these butget no result 1) console.log(stats?._pipeline?.map((item)=> (
              <p > {item[1]} </p>)  and  2) stats._pipeline[1]

Comment: if you have problems with js, maybe ask new question , i use java/clojure in general, but many people can help

Comment: Thank you i will look at that and will ask new question if couldn't make it . Thank you again